# FFMPEG: How to specify -ss and -to as a frame number instead of time

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to ask if there is a way to specify -ss option (start skip) as a number of frames instead of time. I know that there is no way to skip exactly this number of frames (as described in manual), but it would be useful, e.g. if you want to divide your video to parts not exceeding the stupid 4GB filesize limit in FAT32. It would be also useful with -to option.

I believe that there is a way how to specify -ss and -to in frame number, but I do not know how to do it and I am unable to find it in manual.

Comment: Are you looking to extract segments from files without transcoding?

Comment: Exactly. And I would like to do it without using babylonian mathematics, esp. when I am splitting to 3 or more parts. Does not matter if I want to do it with or without transcoding, -ss and -to works both ways. I know that there are some codecs, which cannot be cut to exact frame (e.g. h.264/avc), but another can be (e.g. AVC-Intra). What I don't know is how to specify frame number instead of time. And I discovered, that -ss 00:00:01.2 (expecting 25 fps) does not mean 27th frame as everyone could expect, but 30th frame (secs are interpreted as decimal number) which makes it all more weird.